# What is 'station'?

Tags: bill-and-ted

We should all know that Station is the extraterrestrial that Bill and Ted snagged from heaven.

But at the beginning of the movie, one of Rufus' guests in class shouts 'Station!' And gets a hearty reply of 'Station!'.

Are the two linked? Is station something more? Something linked with the Wyld Stallyns revolution of the future.

Comment: I always assumed there was greater meaning based on context and/or some detail that we just can't hear properly. (How many westerners would realize that the same word with the pitch going up, down, staying even or varying means something entirely different [in other languages.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_%28linguistics%29)  Who knows what we aren't recognizing in an alien language?)

Comment: Or, possibly, it's just their equivalent to ['Smurf.'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs)

Comment: But,  @khw people other than stain say it.

Comment: Well what the smurf!  Or, to say it another way, just as kids used Smurf despite not fully knowing what it might mean, I guessed 'Station' caught on from people hearing Station say it.  Where he might have used it as actual vocabulary, they use it as an expletive (a positive one), an acknowledgement of Station himself, etc.  But what it means in Station's language, we don't know.  It wouldn't be the first time a species got at least nick-named based on a sound it's members made often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alien was called Station thanks to the writers getting drunk and having a crazy moment with a typo.

> "Station started as a typo.
>
> "We deleted a scene (INT. POLICE STATION) & somehow 'STATION' was left
> dangling. We were so crazily punch drunk we started saying
> 'Staaaaaation, Stayyyyyshuuuunnnnn Stayyyyyyyyshun..' in a tinny
> 'Martian voice'."
>
> <sub><sup>[Bill & Ted writer explains why Bogus Journey's alien was called Station](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/news/a845128/bill-ted-bogus-journey-ed-solomon-alien-station/)</sup></sub>

Prior to learning about the alien's name origins, I took 'station' to be a cultural term, like 'cool' or 'awesome' or 'bear good', with the alien just being named after this phrase of awesomenisitude. Given I'd never heard it before, I thought it was the writers trying to introduce this word, and that might still be the case.

Thus in answer to the question, "are the two linked," with the knowledge the name was a mistake, use of the word 'station' throughout the movie, and the alien's name, are unrelated. The alien's name could and should have been something else, with 'station' still used as street slang (whether originating outside or inside the movie).

Comment: Punch-drunk doesn't mean *actually* drunk. It means that they got a bit silly.

Answer (score 13):

Surely this is because Rufus's civilization is based on Wyld Stallyns, and Station was in Wyld Stallyns - getting him from heaven has already happened from their point of view.

Comment: But you find evil bill and Ted saying it through out as well...It seems as though it goes beyond the character.

Comment: @Pureferret - but "station" was a catchphrase used in the Battle of the Bands which was watched by the world and put Wyld Stallyns on the map--and Wyld Stallyns were of central importance to the culture of the future, so it's not that surprising that the phrase would catch on and just become part of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Station was NOT the aliens actual name. It was what Bill and Ted thought their name was because they mis-understood why God said "Station" to them.  God was saying "Cool" or "Excellent" just as everyone else used the word since the beginning of the film.  The aliens themselves likely just repeated the word.
It's likely a time paradox that the word became an expression because of Bill and Ted misusing it in the first place.

Comment: Is there any evidence which means "Station" was actually "Cool" or "Excellent"?

Comment: Just by the context of how it was used at the begining of the film.  If not precisely cool or excellent, then certainly a term of positive acknowledgement or  greeting in the same way that Bill and Ted use "be excellent to each other," "party on" and similar.  Station!

Answer (score -1):

I have always understood that "Station" was a slang term much the same as "cool" or "radical" and meaning much the same thing.

It is even listed in the Urban Dictionary [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=station). Whether it predates the movie as a known slang term is unknown to me.